# How to post binary in Python for Strapi API

Tags: javascript, python, post, binaryfiles, strapi

For Strapi, I am given this JavaScript boilerplate to upload a file from a form. For more information see here: https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/plugins/upload.html#upload-files-related-to-an-entry

```js
  const formElement = document.querySelector('form');

  formElement.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', '/upload');
    request.send(new FormData(formElement));
  });
```

I am writing a Python program. **How do I translate this in Python?**. I am not using a form, I am pulling the file from a location on the drive.

But there is a warning in the documentation: `You have to send FormData in your request body.`

This is what I have so far:

```py
url = f"{strapi_server_url}/api/upload"

headers = {
    'Authorization': f"Bearer {jwt}",
}
file=open(os.getcwd() + f'\\toys\\{filename}', 'rb')
data = file.read()
print(f"LENGTH FILE: {len(data)}")
response = requests.post(url,files={'file': data}, headers=headers)
```

I get a 400 error. 'ValidationError': 'Files are empty'. But I verified the length of the 'data' variable: 5 MB.

Comment: Here is a good article which demonstrates usage of `XMLHttpRequest` to upload files from a form https://attacomsian.com/blog/xhr-node-file-upload

Comment: Ok, now how do I do this in Python with the requests library?

Comment: Alternatively, is there a way to do this in Bash?